# how to manipulate an array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

So, I have this array:

```
Array ( [idservice] => 3 [level0] => 0.35 ) Array ( [idservice] => 3 [level0] =>
0.35 ) Array ( [idservice] => 2 [level0] => 6.00 ) Array ( [idservice] => 2 [level0]
=> 6.00 ) Array ( [idservice] => 100 [level0] => 20.00 ) Array ( [idservice] => 100 
[level0] => 20.00 )
```

i need to make the 3 as a variable add a prefix to it to make it $id_3 and set the level0 as the value of the variable, like this

```
$id_3 = 0.35
```

and I have to do this for all the arrays, so that in the end I would have :

```
$id_3   = 0.35
$id_2   = 2.00
$id_100 = 6.00
```

is that at all possible?
`o` and `i` need `foreach` kind of statement so that, I can get all the variables at one time.

Comment: Why do you want to extract them all as variables? It's going to make your code harder and not easier.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [`extract`](http://php.net/extract) function.
Something on the following lines.

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($yourarray as $array)
{
    $newkey = 'id_'.$array['idservice'];
    $newarray[$newkey] = $array['level0'];
}
extract($newarray);
```

You could use the `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` parameter to prefix `id` before every variable name.
See documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
foreach ($array as $data) {
   $idVar = 'id_'.$data['idservice'];
   $$idVar = $data['level0'];
}
```

will result in:

```
$id_3   = 0.35
$id_2   = 2.00
$id_100 = 6.00
```